# How to import a File path in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to import multiple files in my `App.js` . My folder structure is

```
/src  
   /components       
     layout.js
   App.js  
   index.css
   index.js
```

Here i want to import `layout.js` file from `App.js`. My code is

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from './components/layout';

class App extends React.Component{
   render(){
       return ( 
          <div>
              <p>Hi</p>
          </div>
      );
   }
 }

 export default App;
```

In my code, how to import `layout.js` file ?

Comment: `import Layout from './components/layout';`

Comment: you have already imported it `import Layout from './components/layout';`

Comment: but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, your layout is a component which you can simply import into your main. One good pratcise when creating new component is to create a separate folder inside components folder and create index.js. By doing so you can import components like below:

```
/src
/components
  /layout
    index.js
App.js
index.css
index.js



import React from 'react';
import Layout from './components/layout';

class App extends React.Component{
   render(){
       return ( 
          <div>
              <p>Hi</p>
              <Layout/>
          </div>
      );
   }
 }

 export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you imported Layout correctly. If it is not working, perhaps you forgot to `export default Layout` in layout.js?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use webpack's [resolve.extensions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions) to import file paths that don't end in `.js`