# Relative image paths from js object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path

In a `create-react-app` app, I am using [React Image Gallery](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery). I am having the user select one of my galleries and then pass the array containing the image paths to the `<ImageGallery items={ images } />` component. It works if I use absolute paths, like so:

```
{'images': 
  [
    { original: 'https://domain.tld/image_01.jpg' },
    { original: 'https://domain.tld/image_02.jpg' } 
  ] 
}
```

My file structure is as follows:

```
>src
  >base
   App.js           // this is where the array is assigned to state
  >data
    >containertypes
      >js
       SlideShow.js  // this is where the array is read from props and used in <ImageGallery />
  >img
   image_01.jpg
   image_02.jpg
```

I tried using relative paths like so:

```
{'images': 
  [
    { original: '../../../img/image_01.jpg' },
    { original: '../../../img/image_02.jpg' } 
  ] 
}
```

Unfortunately, to no avail (also tried one less and one more '..'). How can I use relative paths in React without having a chance to use import statements on each image file?

At this point, considering the notorious troubles with paths in React (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213279/how-to-avoid-using-relative-path-imports-redux-action-action1-in-cre) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220622/how-to-import-a-file-path-in-react-js/48220786) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js)) , I do not think that this is a problem with the image gallery component, but a general React issue.

Comment: have you tried `/img/image_01.jpg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your images folder "img" from `src/` to `public/` and add `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` :

```
import React from 'react';
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';
import './App.css';

const images = [
  { original: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/image_01.jpg' },
  { original: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/image_02.jpg' },
];

export default function App() {
  return (
   <ImageGallery items={images} />
  );
}
```